# Can't access plugin variable in a twig template?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, variable

So i've got this little plugin named AnnuaireAdherents with a variable that i try to access from within a template : 

`annuaireadherents/
├── AnnuaireAdherentsPlugin.php
├── services
│   ├── AnnuaireAdherents_Service.php
│   └── Proxy.php
├── twigextensions
│   └── AnnuaireAdherentsTwigExtension.php
└── variables
    └── AnnuaireAdherentsVariable.php`

The variable should return a dynamic array, but let's try a static one first :

```
<?php namespace Craft;

/**
 * Variables provides access to list of adherents inside templates
 */
class AnnuaireAdherentsVariable {

    /**
     * Liste d'adhérents
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function adherents() {
        return array(
            array(
                "raison_sociale" => "JOHN DOE & Co",
                "contact" => "JOHN DOE",
                "cp" => "99999",
                "address1" => "DESTINY STREET",
                "locality" => "NOWHERE",
                "mail" = "john.doe@nowhere.net"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried every namespace variants i could think of to access it inside a template :

```
{% for adh in craft.annuaireAdherents.adherents %}
    {{ adh.raison_sociale }}
{% endfor %}
```

but i keep receiving the error :

> Method "annuaireAdherents" for object "Craft\CraftVariable" does not exist

Is it the correct namespace ?
Do i have to relaunch Apache and Craft between each code modification to retest my variable ?
Could there be another error that is masking me the true cause of this message ?

Thanks a lot for any clue /  direction to investigate.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did you install your plugin in Settings/Plugins?

Comment: Don't be sorry to ask : it was the main cause !

I have to sync with the craft database updated by my coworker, and by doing that, i totally forgot that my plugin would be uninstalled as he doesn't have the plugin yet !!

Thanks a lot for that silly one ! My apologies ! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Reinstalling the plugin after a database update** just solved the problem : the database i sync'ed with didn't have the plugin installed (as it is still in development)

Sorry for that one... :)